# Does Ubuntu Live session write anything on the primary partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, live-cd, root, data-recovery

Here is the situation.I am a duel windows ans ubuntu user. Accidentally I formatted the C partition(root partition of windows).

Now I ran several live ubuntu sessions from CD. And found a way to recover my formatted C partition using testDisk.

testDisk is supposed to revert back my partition to its original state, but only if i hadn't written anything after the format.

My question is, does the live session write anything on the C partition(boot partition) ?

Sometimes i tried to remotely access the pc, while the live session was running. I had to change the host name, root password and other network setting..does this activity may result is some data written on the formatted partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No! If you were changing the settings in Ubuntu, then you were only affecting the temporary RAM drive.

From the [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) about the live cd: A quick demo of Ubuntu. **Try Ubuntu without any changes to your machine!** Windows or whatever you use normally is unaffected after trying this and then rebooting (in 99.999% of cases).

Reasons for Using a LiveCD Session.LiveCD sessions are good to:

- repair or preparation for awkward installations
- fix Windows problems on a machine that doesn't have a dual-boot
- **data recovery**